# Android deep link not working when user just installed app

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have an application which can be opened from a button on a web page. I have an intent filter in my manifest like this:

```
<intent-filter>  
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
     <data android:scheme="example-link"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This works fine if the user does not has the app installed, the link opens Play Store. If the user has the app, then it is opened.

The problem is when user recently installed the application. If the user installs the app but has never opened it, when he selects the URL, Play Store is opened instead of my application. Once the user opens for the first time the app, then all works normally.

Is there any way to open the app always if it is installed?

Answer (score 0):

While generating deep link have you done this

```
 new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder("com.example.packagename")
```

Comment: Thats pretty much a guess so its have to be a comment..  I think this question lacks [mcve] for creating links.

Comment: The link is generted on JS, the purpose is to open the Android app from a button in a web. So I'm not generating it on my application.

Comment: you just have to mention there package name of your android app

Comment: The button calls this url:

intent://example-link://param1?domain=example-domain&id=abcde12345#Intent;scheme=example-link;package=com.example.app;end

This is working fine if user has opened the app at least one time.